# Storing mdf and ldf sql files in OneDrive or iCloud drive

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to change the connection string in a VS 2017 C# web application Core 2 project's connection string to use OneDrive or iCloud as storage medium?

Since I work on my laptop, at home and at work (hobby programmer, not professional) I'd like the mdf and ldf files available in the same location regardless of where I am.

I do save the entire project (most of the time) in OneDrive, should seem reasonable to be able to save the sql files there as well.

trying to eliminate using Azure for development, bad practice I know..

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills...not sure how...just set Server= to the path?

Comment: `not sure how..` What is your current connection string?

Comment: _To be clear, this is a terrible idea since it will only ever **possibly** work if your work and home machine are not on at the same time._

Answer (score 1):

You can if you utilize the syncing functionality. In other words, you cannot simply change the connection string to the URL of the database file online. Even if SQL Server Express could read from that, it wouldn't be able to do writes over HTTP. However, OneDrive and similar online storage providers often include a utility that propagates your online files to actual filesystem locations on each connected PC. I know, for example, that once you set up OneDrive in Windows 10, it will sync your Documents directory by default. If you store the file there, it should then be synced to all other connected computers.